# How can you upload json to S3 via javascript code for browser extension?

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-s3, browser-extension

I've made a javascript browser extension for google chrome that is logging urls. I want to send a json containing each url and time of visit to my S3 bucket via my javascript code. However, I can only see a way to do this with node.js which I believe is not compatible with browser extensions.

Is there a specific way to do this that I am not aware of?